# Consumer: Messages lost even commit and syncpoint is used when queue manager is disconnected

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

Messages get lost in this scenario:

1 Consumers read messages off the queue, and

2 before commit it, queue manager disconnect or crashes

3 the message is no longer in the queue.

Should't Commit throw exception in situation like this? Because client might crash before calling Commit.

What is the correct way to implement it?

```
 Open(ConnectionMode.Read);
    var message = GetMessage();

     //process other works when queue manager is disconnected

    queueManager.Commit(); //this still runs successfully                
    queue.Close();           
    queueManager.Disconnect();


  public string GetMessage()
    {
        const int MaxMessageSizeInBytes = 8000;
        const int ReadTimeoutInMilliseconds = 3000;

        message = new MQMessage { Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING };
        var mqMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions
        {
            WaitInterval = ReadTimeoutInMilliseconds,
            Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
            | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT  //use syncpoint for consumer acknowledgment
        };

        var content = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
        message.ClearMessage();

        return content;
    }

    public IMessage Get()
    {
        var mqMessage = new MQMessage { Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING };
        var mqMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions
        {
            WaitInterval = ReadTimeoutInMilliseconds,
            Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT
        };

        Connection.MqQueue.Get(mqMessage, mqMessageOptions, MaxMessageSizeInBytes);

        return mqMessage.MapToMessage();
    }


    public void Open(connectionMode connectionMode)
    {
        var connectionSettings = new Hashtable
        {
            {MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
            {MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT }
        };

        int openOptions = 0;

        switch (connectionMode)
        {
            case connectionMode.Read:
                openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                break;
            case connectionMode.Write:
                openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                break;
        }


        MqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(_queueManagerName, connectionSettings);
        MqQueue = MqQueueManager.AccessQueue(_queueName, openOptions);
    }
```

MQ Server V8 on Windows

.NET Client: 8.0.0.5

Comment: That is completely different issue!

Comment: Plus, there is NO answer to the question. Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

> 2 before commit it, queue manager disconnect or crashes

Please describe how you simulated this.  Did you just pull the network cable from the client server/PC/laptop?  How long did you wait?  The default TCP timeout is 2 hours.  The queue manager won't know that the client is gone until the TCP timeout period expires.  After that, the queue manager should make the message available again.

Comment: I right click the queue manager from MQ Explorer, and click Disconnect. No crashes which I will remove. Disconnect does not mean the queue manager disconnected? I can Stop Command Server too, which might mean something else too.

Comment: @Pingpong I am not sure since I do not use MQ Explorer but believe that is just telling MQ Explorer to disconnect from the queue manager, the queue manager will still be running.  If you go to a command line on the server with the queue manger (windows or unix) and run the command `dspmq` it should show you the queue manager names defined and current status such as "Running".

Comment: Roger, if you are running MQ Server v7.0.1 or higher and and MQ Client at the same level by default there is bidirectional heart beating of the SVRCONN channel.  The timeout is either 2xHBINT if the HBINT < 60, or HBINT+60 if he HBINT >= 60.  The default HBINT is 300, so you can expect a TIMEOUT of 360 seconds (6 minutes) with default settings.  We set this much lower so timeout happens in a more reasonable time, I  have found HBINT 15 to be a good number, then timeout is in 30 seconds.

Comment: @Pingpong Disconnecting from MQ Explorer has no bearing on your application or any other application connected to the queue manager.  You need to either unplug the network cable from the server where your application is running or kill your application.